# How to capitalize first and last letters of line in a Python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
word = input()

word= word.lower()

line = 'ilovecat'

for i in range(0, len(line)):

        if word[0] == line[i]:

            line1 = line[i:]
            line2 = line[:i-2]
            aline = line1+line2
            aline = aline.capitalize()
            print(aline)
        else:
            continue
```

The input is "CUTE".
I want to make the output like "CatilovE" but my code prints "Catilove".
I already tried `aline.upper(i-2)` in this way and of course it didn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: Just try it without loops and anything else: `line.capitalize()[:-1] + line[-1].capitalize()`

Comment: Try `b = line[0].upper()+line[1:-1]+line[-1].upper()`. This capitalizes the first letter, adds the middle letters unchanged, and then adds the last letter capitalized. `b` is the new string you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
v="HELLO WORLD"
t=v[0:1].upper()+v[1:-1].lower()+v[-1:].upper()
print(t)
```

It prints

```
Hello worlD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
word = input('Enter the sentence : ')

word = word[:1].upper()+word[1:len(word)-1].lower()+word[len(word)-1:].upper()

print(word)
```

The output will be:

> hello Mrs
>
> Hello mrS